# How would I retrieve data from a CQL table by columns sno and roll_no?

Tags: cassandra

How do i Fetch name and Grade on the basis of Sno and Roll no in the below json using Cassandra Query language, Please suggest "select" query.

```
{
      "Sno":1,
      "School name":"Ramjas School",
      "StudentDetails":[{
        "Roll_no":1,
        "Name":"Nick",
        "Grade":"A"
      },
      {
        "Roll_no":2,
        "Name":"Allen",
        "Grade":"B"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here table is created with these below queries:-

```
CREATE type student_details
(
  Roll_no int,
  Name text,
  Grade text
);

CREATE TABLE products(
  Sno int PRIMARY KEY,
  School_name  text,
  StudentDetails list<FROZEN<student_details>>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to query by `sno` and `roll_no` because your table's primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (sno)
)
```

means that the only valid query is:

```
SELECT ... FROM products WHERE sno = ?
```

You will not be able to filter by `roll_no` because it is not part of the primary key.

In Cassandra data modelling, you need to design your tables based on the application query. If your application query is "get student name and grade for sno X and roll_no Y", you need to model your table like:

```
CREATE TABLE products_by_sno (
   sno int,
   roll_no int,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY (sno, roll_no)
)
```

With this schema, the table is partitioned by `sno` and clustered by `roll_no` meaning each `sno` partition contains one or more rows of `roll_no`.

This query will return all the rows for a specific `sno`:

```
SELECT ... FROM products_by_sno WHERE sno = ?
```

To retrieve a specific `roll_no`:

```
SELECT ... FROM products_by_sno WHERE sno = ? AND roll_no = ?
```

In Cassandra, the possible CQL queries are determined by the table schema so it is important to know the application queries before designing the corresponding tables. Cheers!